# Regex for replacing digits in a string

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a string "AAAAAAA02" and i want to replace it with "AAAAAAA01" ie just number alone.
I have tried following sed commands which is not working:

```
sed -e "s|AAAAAAA\\d+$|AAAAAAA01|g;" 
sed -E "s|(AAAAAAA.+)\d+|AAAAAAA01|g;"
sed -E "s|(AAAAAAA.+)\\d+|AAAAAAA01|g;"
sed -E "s|AAAAAAA(\\d+)|AAAAAAAD01|g;"
```

Basically i need a regex but if someone can help me with sed command, then it would be great.!!

Edit:
I knew this can be replaced as hardcoded value say 01/02. But there are plenty of lines in a file and i want to replace it generically. 
I require a RegEx to clean it up generically.

Comment: The `;` at the end must be removed. `\d` should be changed into `[0-9]`. If a group is used in the regex, why not use a backreference in the replacement part?

Comment: just wanted to know, whomever gave negative to question, leave a feedback how to improve. why and on what basis you think this question is not useful?

Comment: Your "which is not working" does not sound clear. Usually, it is advisable to explain what exactly goes wrong, are there any error messages, etc.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, in future, i will take care of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `;` at the end must be removed. `\d` should be changed into `[0-9]`. If a group is used in the regex, why not use a backreference in the replacement part?

Use

```
s='AAAAAAA02'
echo $s | sed -E "s|(A{7})[0-9]+|\101|g"
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/d55o7K).

The `-E` option enables the POSIX ERE syntax (no need to escape `(...)` to create a capturing group and no need to escape `+` and `{...}` quantifiers).

The pattern matches:

- `(A{7})` - Group 1: seven `A`s
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits

The replacement inserts the contents inside Group 1 (`\1`) and adds `01` to the value.

NOTE: If the `A...<digits>` must be matched as a whole word, use word boundaries, `\b`, round the pattern (`sed -E "s|\b(A{7})[0-9]+\b|\101|g"`).